# Error add my project module Angular 2.0+ calendar

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

My project is written in Angular2. When trying to add a calendar [GitHub Angular2 calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar)  module on my site are show errors. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v1RY.png)

I do not know what to do.
The system-config too have added this way.

Comment: You should load the js from `'node_modules/angular-calendar/angular-calendar.js' instead`

Comment: Your reference to the location of the module is incorrect - it looks like you've put `'angular-calender'`, however it's more likely something like `'angular-calender/angular-calender'` - this tells Angular to look for `angular-calender.js` within the `angular-calender` directory.